# Export Voyager map from QGIS to GeoServer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, export

I found a map Voyager (no labels) via QMS plugin in QGIS. How to export this map from QGIS to GeoServer? I tried with GeoCat bridge plugin but the layer with map is not supported.

Comment: What sort of map/layer is it?

Comment: @IanTurton there is a link to all details about this map. https://qms.nextgis.com/geoservices/2634/

Answer (score 1):

That is a TMS layer, GeoServer can cascade WMS and WMTS layers but there is currently no support for TMS layers. It would be possible to add the support by modifying the WMTS code as the underlying GeoTools code does support TMS servers.

Comment: But can't I just somehow save this map from the link to another format and then send to GeoServer?

Comment: No, at each scale there is a set of little images the fit together as a base map. Why can't you just include that service in your client

Comment: It's about the licence and limit of calls. I prefer to have my own server as I possess high-performance dedicated servers. An additional reason could be that I thought about adding some other data to this map in a later step. But it's not high prior for now.